# AJAX generated order list li id not post via data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting the list of root folders of OneDrive and sub folders using AJAX post using the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".driveFolders li").click(function(){
        var folderId = $(this).attr( "id" );
        var objlst=    $(this);
        var request;
        request = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: {'id': folderId},
            ContentType: 'application/json'
        });

        request.done(function( response ) {
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            var html="";
            for(var i = 0, l = result.length; i < l; i++){
                var subFolderID = result[i].id;
                html += "<li  id="+subFolderID+"'>" + result[i].name +  "</li>";

            }
            $("#childern").html(html);
        });
    })
})
```

It returns the list of all files and folders. Now, I got the AJAX to generate data of li elements and I am sending a AJAX request again using the following code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#childern li", function () {

    var subFolderID = $(this).attr("id");

    var objlst = $(this);
    var request;
    request = $.ajax({
        context: this,
        url: url,
        method: "POST",

        data: { 'id': subFolderID },
        ContentType: 'application/json'
    });
    request.done(function (response) {

        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

        var html = "";
        for (var j = 0, l = result.length; j < l; j++) {


        }
        $("#childern").html(html);
    });
});
```

It returns an error

> folders does not exist.

While sending the folder id manually, I receive all files. Here is my controller code:

```
public function GetFolderContent(){

    $this->load->library('STOneDrive');

    if (!$this->stonedrive->is_Connected) {
        $refreshToken = "";
        $this->stonedrive->Reconnect($refreshToken);
    }

    $contents = $this->stonedrive->LoadRootFolders(urldecode($this->input->post('id')));
    $result = array();
    foreach($contents as $content){
        array_push($result,array('id' => $content->getId(),'name'=>$content->getName(),'size'=> ''));
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake to append id to li tag:
change

```
html += "<li  id="+subFolderID+"'>" + result[i].name +  "</li>";
```

to following

```
 html += "<li  id='"+subFolderID+"'>" + result[i].name +  "</li>";
```

Comment: thanks for correction now working fine. now i need a treeview folders and sub folders suggest me how i made my tree any idea exampe

Answer (score 0):

In ajax code method replace with **type** and content-type with **dataType**.